# Direct link to asset

Tags: templating, assets

I'm trying to send some assets links through email, but using `{{ siteUrl  ~ file.link }}` returns an url with double forwards slashes like: `http://example.com//public/assets/sdfsdfds.jpeg`

I couldn't find a method on the **AssetsFileModel** that generates a direct link to it. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you just use `<a href="{{ file.url }}">`? So, without the siteUrl part? If your Asset source's URL setting is correct (so, the complete url, preferably using {siteUrl}), that should do the trick ...

Comment: I tried that, but it only returns the file path, like `/public/assets/sdfsdfds.jpeg` without the website url.

Comment: And what's your assets source's URL setting?

Comment: File System Path: {basePath}/assets/uploads/

URL: /public/assets/uploads/

Comment: Url should be the complete url to your file, so for instance {siteUrl}public/assets/uploads. That way, {{ file.url }} always works, even if you change the siteUrl config setting.

Comment: Ohh man, that's it. Haha. Thanks for your time @paul-verheul appreciate that. You might wanna add that to your answer for future reference. Thanks again.